# How create .Net Maui ContentPage using c# instead of xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

The [.Net Maui ContentPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/contentpage) doc gives a XAML example. But no c# example.

How do I create a ContentPage using only c#?

Comment: Right click on project-> Add -> New Item -> .NET MAUI-> .NET MAUI ContentPage(C#)

Comment: Good point. Thank you for pointing that out - I'll add it to answer. FYI I wrote this Q&A for someone who didn't know about "c# markup". The hard part isn't creating that class file, its understanding what to do with it. Though I see that using the correct item gives an excellent starting point - maybe that is all most people need to get them started!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- The concept is "c# markup".
- Getting started: Right click on project-> Add -> New Item -> .NET MAUI-> `.NET MAUI ContentPage (C#)` or `.NET MAUI ContentView (C#)`.
- If a Maui doc doesn't (yet) have the info you need, google `xamarin forms SomeUIElement class` for the `SomeUIElement` API.

---

Maui "API" docs aren't there yet (currently there is only a page giving "higher-level" explanation of each class), so more information can be found by searching for the **corresponding Xamarin Forms class**.
Google `xamarin forms contentpage class` to find:

> [Xamarin.Forms / ContentPage Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.contentpage?view=xamarin-forms).

There, we see c# example:

```cs
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ContentPageExample
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        public static Page GetMainPage ()
        {    
            return new ContentPage { 
                Content = new Label {
                    Text = "Hello, Forms!",
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                },
            };
        }

        public App ()
        {
            MainPage = GetMainPage();
        }
    }
}
```

The `App` details may be slightly different for Maui; the part of this code we care about is:

```cs
            return new ContentPage { 
                Content = new Label {
                    Text = "Hello, Forms!",
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                },
            };
```

This works as-is in Maui. (Compiler warns that `LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand` is deprecated; but discussing that is beyond scope of this answer.)

---

**REUSABLE VIEW**

If you want to refer to a UI element from elsewhere in xaml or code, define a subclass of an existing UI element.

Thanks to Paramjit for pointing out that the first step is to Add the appropriate item to project. For `ContentPage`, that is:

> Right click on project-> Add -> New Item -> .NET MAUI-> `.NET MAUI ContentPage (C#)`

For `ContentView` (as below), that step is:

> Right click on project-> Add -> New Item -> .NET MAUI-> `.NET MAUI ContentView (C#)`

---

Source file MyContentView.cs:

```cs
namespace MyViews
{
    public class MyContentView : ContentView
    {
        public MyContentView {
            //NO "InitializeComponent()" because doing it all in c#.

            Content = new Label {
                Text = "Hello, Maui!"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage in XAML:

```xml
<SomeClass ...
    xmlns:myviews="clr-namespace:MyViews"
    ...>
    ...
    <myviews:MyContentView ... />
</SomeClass>
```

Usage in c# as part of c# markup:

```cs
using MyViews;

    ...
    var page = new ContentPage {
        Content = new MyContentView()
    }
```

---

**ADVANCED**

Subclassing `ContentView` is one way to make a "custom control" in Maui.

- To define custom properties, read about "custom views" and "BindableProperties". (I don't have specific links to recommend at this time. Feel free to add such links as comments.)
- A more advanced way is to create a custom handler.
  See [Creating a .NET MAUI Maps Control](https://www.cayas.de/blog/dotnet-maui-custom-map-handler).

---

**MORE INFO**

Defining UI elements in c# is referred to as "c# markup".

See [Introducing C# Markup for Xamarin.Forms](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/c-sharp-markup-for-xamarin-forms/).

And [Xamarin Community Toolkit C# Markup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/markup). NOTE: The Nuget mentioned there **is no longer required**.

Comment: You don't have to use C# Markup - you can just use native C#. C# Markup just enables you to write it in a Markup style.

Comment: Good point. Though I am not aware of any reason NOT to use c# markup. It is (slightly) more concise, and closer to the "declarative" style of XAML. This makes it both easier to read (if you are familiar with XAML), and easier to move logic between XAML and c#, when that is desired. For example, if you have some XAML, but find that you can't code a needed expression (too complex for XAML), you move it to c# markup. Then can insert calls to parameterized c# methods that do the needed work. Thus have full power of c# rather than writing clumsy "converters" for XAML. Best of both worlds.

Comment: Actually, looking at my c# for UI, I don't strictly use markup style. Works fine to use whichever c# representation is convenient. I use "markup" to nest elements in a single statement. But I often apply operators as separate lines of code, rather than the "this().that().somethingelse()" markup style.

Comment: "rather than writing clumsy "converters" for XAML" - by not using XAML at all then don't need converters at all. Win-win. It's annoying that MAUI hasn't provided C# options in the templates (like Xamarin had).

Comment: FWIW: "don't need converters" is "a win" - it is *half* of the "win-win" I describe. The other half is maintaining the markup structure, while in c#. Given that you are happy writing in plain old c#, my comment is not relevant to you. Rather, it is for anyone else who comes along, and wants some correlation between xaml and c#. For example, they might wish to convert existing xaml into c#, in order to enhance it. Some use of markup style makes the c# more similar to the xaml (as you know). That's all I was trying to say.

Comment: The question wasn't about correlation between XAML and C#. The question was how to make a Page using C#. Your answer said to use C# Markup, but you don't have to do that, so for anyone coming along who wants to know how to do it, my comment is pointing out you don't have to use C# Markup - you can just use out-of-the-box C# to do it. Some people do actually think you have to have a special library to do it (C# Markup, Comet, etc.), which is a misconception. No packages needed at all.